# Remove PowerShell object properties that match pattern

Tags: powershell

Given an example object (coverted from JSON):

```
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Pablo",
  "UnwantedProperty1XOXO": true,
  "UnwantedProperty2XOXO": false,
  "Things": [
    {
      "Name": "Something",
      "UnwantedProperty3XOXO": true
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```

**How can I remove all properties that match a pattern?**  In the example I want to remove the three properties that end in `XOXO`.

My current approach is to use `-ExcludeProperty` like this:

```
$myObject | Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty *XOXO
```

That only removes the first two properties.  I need to reach deeper into the collection of `Things` as well.  The object will change as well so I can't hardcode a check for `Things` and there could be many collections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, **`Select-Object -ExcludeProperty` does *not* act *recursively*** - it only acts on the *immediate* properties - so **a custom solution is needed**.

Defining function `Remove-Property`, printed below, should provide the desired recursive logic:

```bash
$sampleJson = @'
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Pablo",
  "UnwantedProperty1XOXO": true,
  "UnwantedProperty2XOXO": false,
  "Things": [
    {
      "Name": "Something",
      "UnwantedProperty3XOXO": true
    }
  ]
}
'@

$sampleJson | ConvertFrom-Json | 
  Remove-Property -NamePattern *XOXO |
    ConvertTo-Json
```

**An important aside**: `ConvertFrom-Json` limits parsing to depth of just *2* levels by default, so you may have to specify a greater depth with `-Depth <n>`.
This problematic default behavior is discussed in [GitHub issue #8393](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8393).

The result is as follows - note how all properties ending in `XOXO`, across all levels of the hierarchy, were removed:

```bash
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Pablo",
  "Things": [
    {
      "Name": "Something"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

#### `Remove-Property` source code

**Important**: `Remove-Property`:

- assumes that the input objects are *custom objects* (`[pscustomobject]`), such as created by `ConvertFrom-Json`.
- it modifies these objects *in place*, in addition to *outputting* the modified object; this differs from `Select-Object`, which creates *new* objects from the input.

```bash
function Remove-Property {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, Position = 0)]
    [object] $InputObject,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 1)]
    [string] $NamePattern
  )
  process {
    foreach ($el in $InputObject) {
      foreach ($propName in $el.psobject.Properties.Name) {
        if ($propName -like $NamePattern) {
          $el.psobject.Properties.Remove($propName)
        }
        else {
          $null = Remove-Property -InputObject $el.$propName -NamePattern $NamePattern
        }
      }
    }
    $InputObject
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't prefer this solution, but it does seem easier than recursively traversing an object's nested properties of unknown depths.

```
$json = @'
{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Pablo",
  "UnwantedProperty1XOXO": true,
  "UnwantedProperty2XOXO": false,
  "Things": [
    {
      "Name": "Something",
      "UnwantedProperty3XOXO": true
    }
  ]
}
'@

$filter = "XOXO"
$json -replace ".*$filter.*\r?\n" -replace ",(?=\r?\n\W+})" | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work.

```
filter Remove-Property ($Name) {
    $queue = [Collections.Generic.Queue[object]]::new(@(Get-Variable _))
    while ($queue.Count) {
        foreach ($elem in $queue.Dequeue().Value) {
            $props = $elem.psobject.Properties
            foreach ($p in $props) {
                if ($p.Name -like $Name) { $props.Remove($p.Name) } else { $queue.Enqueue($p) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The usage is as follows.

```
$myObject | Remove-Property -Name "*XOXO"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ConvertFrom-Json` Cmdlet by default has a depth of 2. This is most likely causing your issue.

To fix, use this `ConvertFrom-Json` command:

```
ConvertFrom-Json $input -Depth 10
```

Reference: [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-6)

Comment: While pointing out the surprising default behavior of `ConvertFrom-Json` is a good idea in general, it is _incidental_ to the OP's question, given that the sample JSON doesn't exceed depth 2. What they want is _recursive_ exclusion of properties by name, which `Select-Object` doesn't offer.

Comment: Good to know but that isn't the issue for me.  Thanks.